# Create a PK in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure

When clicking the key icon in SSMS the syntax it uses create a new FK is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.territory 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_territory 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (item_id)
                    WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
                          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

A few questions on this:

- Why is the `PRIMARY KEY` defined as `CLUSTERED`? What if it were defined without that?
- What are all the statistics and statements in the parenthesis for?
- What would be the most basic `ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (column);` statement in SQL Server?
- What's the equivalent of `AUTOINCREMENT` in SQL Server?

Comment: All this information is already clearly explained in the official documentation... better than we can explain.

Comment: "[What's the equivalent of AUTOINCREMENT in sql server?](https://www.google.com/search?q=What%27s+the+equivalent+of+AUTOINCREMENT+in+sql+server)"

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you elaborate your question as to why create a table without a clustered key?
Your statement to create a autoincrement is called Identity, in this case, start by 1 and increment with 1, the primary key can be defined after the column if not a compound key and you're not fuzzy about the auto-assigned name

```
Create table Table1(
  [ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY (1, 1)
)


Create table Table1(
  [ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1)
)
```

Comment: I see, so is the clustered index used to specify the physical location of the records at the storage level? That is, the main (usually unique) index is the clustered one and all others cannot be so?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 that is close (and fairly useful way to look at it) but maybe not 100% correct. It doesn't necessarily refer to the physical location (e.g., on disk) but instead how the data is stored within the table (e.g., analagous to a large Excel file stored in multiple places on disk, but when you open it, it's in order). Another way to view it, is that the clustered index is stored with all the other data for the table as well; the clustered index defines the ordering within that dataset. As the data needs to be stored somehow anyway, a clustered index is often used to help with sorts.

Comment: @seanb thanks! Out of curiosity, why is it named "clustered" then? Why not something like 'physical' or something more obvious.

Comment: Tbh I have no clue. It may be it keeps the similar rows 'clustered' together. It may be that it 'clusters' the rest of the data with the index values. Update to the example. Imagine an Excel file sorted by column A - its clustered index (CX). If you had to insert a line into the file, it would need to find the appropriate location to maintain the sort, and insert a new row there. In contrast, a heap (table without CX) the new row could go anywhere. However, the CX helps when you need to find specific row(s); in a heap you need to read the complete dataset as you don't know where it is.